# Separation days and made average in queryset for chart

Tags: python, loops, django-queryset

I just have a queryset that return collection of records that have amount , I wanna show chart by average in everyday . this is my code but I think it's really awful for performance.
any advice to make it better?

```
month_query = table.objects.filter(time__gt=datetime.now() - timedelta(30))
for day in range(1, 32):
        cnt = 0
        amount = 0
        amount_avg = 0
        for obj in month_query:
            if obj.time.day == day:
                amount += obj.amount
                cnt += 1
        if cnt > 0:
            amount_avg = amount / cnt
        month_days_avg.insert(day, amount_avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `values` and `annotate` to let django to do that:

```
from django.db.models import Avg
month_days_avg = MyModel.objects.filter(time__gt=datetime.now() - timedelta(30)).values('time').annotate(average_amount=Avg('amount'))
```

The above query will result a list of dates and averages

Comment: in this way I just get one variable with all times avarage not avarage by everyday ?